# prove that $m^{*}$ is a translation invariant

Tags: measure-theory

I was doing this exercise from royden's Real analysis book where other measure was defined
[image]

this is the exercise, prove that $m^{*}$ is a translation invariant
PD: $ m $ is a translation invariant if $ E $ is a set for which $ m $ is defined and if $ E + y $ is the set $\{x + y: x \in E \}$ obtained by replacing each point $x \in E$ by the point $ x + y $, then $ m (E + y) = m (E) $

my idea is the following let $E$ be a set of real numbers and let $y\in \mathbb{R}$. If $\{I_n\}$ is a countable collection of open intervals such that $E\subset \bigcup I_n$, then $E+y \subset \bigcup (I_n+y)$ so $m^{*}(E+y)=m^{*}(E)$
but I don't know how to conclude that $ m ^ {*} (E + y) \leq m ^ {*} (E) $

Answer (score 1):

If $I_1, I_2, ... $ are intervals covering $A$, then what can you say about $I_1 + y, I_2 +y, ...$? What about $m^*(I_k + y)$ in relation to $m^*(I_k)$?